Netty - How to pass a string message to client when server (API) was called?
I have my postman ready to connect to localhost's API server.
Once my postman is connected to my API server, I want my API server to send a String message to TCP Client's server using socket connection (Netty)
Once my API server gets called, the router will direct the connection to API
Sends connection to API using API path from postman -> my server's RouterConfig.java file receives it
then routes it using
POSTMAN host: localhost:9009/test/test2
RouterConfig.java
public class RouterConfig {
    RouterFuction<?> testRoutes(TestHandler handler){
        return route().path("/test", builder -> builder
            .POST("/test2", accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), handler::test2)
        )
    }
}

and in MonitoringHandler.java I have
public class TestHandler {
    public Mono<ServerResponse> test2(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(SearchDto.class)
                .doOnNext(body -> {
                    log.info(body.toString());
                })
                .flatMap(body -> {
                    try {
                        return ServerResponse.ok()
                                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .body(testService.test2(String.valueOf(body)), String.class);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                });
    }
}

and in  testService.java I  have
    public static List<Connection> getConns() {
        return conns;
    }
    private static List<Connection> conns = new ArrayList<Connection>();


    public String test2(String msg) {
        conns.get(0).outbound().sendString(Mono.just("ttteessstt")).then().block();
        return "";
    }

Then when I call the API the message "ttteessstt" gets passed to client's server indeed
but I do not understand why it works since I wrote then().block() < which triggers error on console for API server.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-3.

So my question  is, why does it work with .block()? (If I remove block(), the message wont be passed)
and also, how can I rewrite my testService.java code to make it better? I feel like there will  be a simpler way to do this but can't find it..
I tried using writeAndFlush but my testService seems to be not finding ChannelHandlerContext`` ctx I tried conns.get(0).outbound().sendString(Mono.just("ttteessstt")).then()because I thought this would work originally but it did not, that's why I addedblock()` in the end.
I wanted to use ctx (ChannelHandlerContext or ChannelHandler) to use .flushAndWrite but I keep getting my ctx as null (because I declare it only in service file, I tried getting as a parameter but I dunno how to pass it in router).
